# Turn off Concurrent Sessions Allowed

Tags: customer, sessions, customer-session

Is it possible to turn off Concurrent Sessions?

We had a pen test and it flagged concurrent sessions.

> Weak Session Management - Concurrent Sessions Allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC this is controllable at the WAF or by enabling some of the options below in `System > Configuration > Web > Session Validation`

[image]

Comment: Great to know there's a solution to this - would you mind elaborating on how to implement the solution Phil?